# TypeError: document.createElement is not a function- React, Mocha, JSDOM testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, tdd, jsdom

I had previously written a testing script which very much similar to the below given script. It was running fine with following version of libraries

```
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
"jquery": "^2.2.1",
"jsdom": "^8.1.0",
"mocha": "^2.4.5",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7"
```

I modified the way to create DOM using `jsdom` so that, the script runs with following version of libaries.

```
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jsdom": "^11.6.2",
"mocha": "^5.0.1",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2"
```

However I am getting an error as given below:

```
 App
    1) "before each" hook for "renders something"


  0 passing (31ms)
  1 failing

  1) App
       "before each" hook for "renders something":
     TypeError: document.createElement is not a function
      at Object.renderIntoDocument (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:741:24)
      at renderComponent (test/test_helper.js:21:40)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/components/app_test.js:8:17)
```

Here is my app testing file

```
import { renderComponent , expect } from '../test_helper';
import App from '../../src/components/App';

describe('App' , () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = renderComponent(App);
  });

  it('renders something', () => {
    expect(component).to.exist;
  });
});
```

Here is my testing helper file

```
import _$ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import {JSDOM} from 'jsdom';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiJquery from 'chai-jquery';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../src/reducers';

global.document = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.window;
console.log(global.document);
global.navigator = global.window.navigator;
const $ = _$(window);

chaiJquery(chai, chai.util, $);

function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
  const componentInstance =  TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <div></div>
  );

  return $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance));
}

$.fn.simulate = function(eventName, value) {
  if (value) {
    this.val(value);
  }
  TestUtils.Simulate[eventName](this[0]);
};

export {renderComponent, expect};
```

I had already searched for solution but unable to find any breakthrough. Can anybody of you can tell me why `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` is not able to create a simple div.

**Note:** I have purposely placed a `div` inside `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` call so that the test always pass for debuging purpose.

Comment: Maybe this note is important: "You will need to have `window`, `window.document` and `window.document.createElement` globally available before you import React. Otherwise React will think it can’t access the DOM and methods like `setState` won’t work." Ref https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument

Comment: Also, I would totally recommend you use Jest + Enzyme to test your app. The method you are using is too bloated and uses jQuery. Your life will be a lot easier with Enzyme.

Comment: @nbkhope how to do that in my file. I think I had already done so???

Answer (score 2):

Change the lines of JSDOM by :

```
global.dom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.navigator = global.window.navigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
function documentmock() {
  var storage = {};

  return {
    getElementById: function (id) {
      return {
        getBoundingClientRect: function () {
          return {
            top: 701,
            bottom: 702,
          };
        },
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
      };
    },
    createElement: function (id) {
      return {
        width: 1000,
        height: 500,
        getContext: function () {
          return {
            drawImage: function () {},
          };
        },
        toDataURL: function () {
          return {
            replace: function () {},
          };
        },
        touchAction: '',
      };
    },
  };
}
```

```js
describe('VerificarRPH tests', () => {
  global.document = sinon.spy();

  beforeEach(() => {
    global['document'] = documentmock();
  });
});
```